# How can I create a Column in pandas from a different column, matching a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame in pandas and one of the columns has a bunch of location numbers.
Ex:

```
    location
 1. 33
 2. 223
 3. 66
```

so what I want to do is create another column that translates these numbers to region number from a list.
ex:

```
list = [[33, 428], [223, 691], [521, 53], [83, 96], [423, 614], [360, 311], [55, 66]]

regionNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

so the result should be

```
location region
33       1 
223      2
66       7
```

so the way that I tried to do this is

```
        def regionid():
            i = 0
            for row in list:
                for item in row:
                    if dataframe["location"] == item:
                        return regionNumber[i]
                i = i + 1

        dataframe['Region'] = dataframe.apply(regionid(), axis=1)
```

I keep getting 
"
 f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
"
I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: do not use keyword (`list`) as your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and use it in [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
lst = [[33, 428], [223, 691], [521, 53], [83, 96], [423, 614], [360, 311], [55, 66]]
regionNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

lookup = {location : r for locations, r  in zip(lst, regionNumber) for location in locations }

df['region'] = df['location'].map(lookup)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   location  region
0        33       1
1       223       2
2        66       7
```

This part:

```
lookup = {location : r for locations, r  in zip(lst, regionNumber) for location in locations }
```

is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), (see more on comprehensions [here](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)). It is a Python expression for creating dictionaries, is equivalent to the following nested for loop:

```
lookup = {} 
for locations, r in zip(lst, regionNumber):
    for location in locations:
        lookup[location] = r
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for me! If you don't mind, can you explain to me what the lookup part does?

Comment: Thank you this really helps

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
region_map = dict(zip(regionNumber, list))
df['region'] = df['location'].map(region_map)
```

Comment: This do not work because the elements of `list` are not hashable

Comment: Should it work if they are reversed so that regionNumber is the key?

Comment: It builds a dictionary, but it do not work in pandas

Comment: Which part doesn't work, .map()? In that case the OP could use .replace(), no?